# Facebook Audience Overlap via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

Is there a way to query the overlap feature as it's possible in the Business Manager via the php sdk for the marketing API?

I'm thinking sending two or more audience IDs of existing audiences and getting the overlap back? I couldn't find anything in the docs so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No. There is currently no php sdk support for this and the API call is not documented.

If you are willing to make direct call you could call `graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_< acctid >/audienceoverlap?access_token=< access_token >&comparison_ids=["< audienceid >"]&pivot_id=< audienceid >`

Most likely you'll need the browser's access token for this.

Answer (score 0):

This call is working at api v10.0 but it no longer exist

The old call is
act_id/audienceoverlap?pivot_id=6124596383156&{comparison_ids=["audince1_id","audince2_id"]}