# Facebook Audience Overlap via API not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I trying to call to overlap api via facebook graph api

The only source I find to facebook overlap is here

[Facebook Audience Overlap via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531722/facebook-audience-overlap-via-api)

But when I trying it really not work

The call is in api v10.0

act_10202169727663069/audienceoverlap?pivot_id=6124596383156&{comparison_ids=["6124720495756","6122310977756"]}

The answer I get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (audienceoverlap) on node type (AdAccount)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Avf-Fn29XQoHMU3bAxGNQBc" 
  }
}
```

Debug information

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/act_10202169727663069/audienceoverlap?pivot_id=6124596383156&%7Bcomparison_ids=%5B%226124720495756%22%2C%226122310977756%22%5D%7D&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "read_insights",
      "ads_management",
      "ads_read",
      "business_management",
      "pages_manage_ads",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": "10224770822076304",
    "app_id": 987735165367365
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {
    "pivot_id": "6124596383156",
    "{comparison_ids": "[\"6124720495756\",\"6122310977756\"]}"
  }
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (audienceoverlap) on node type (AdAccount)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "Avf-Fn29XQoHMU3bAxGNQBc"
    }
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=act_10202169727663069%2Faudienceoverlap%3Fpivot_id%3D6124596383156%26%7Bcomparison_ids%3D[%226124720495756%22%2C%226122310977756%22]%7D&version=v10.0
```

Comment: If you don’t find this mentioned in the official documentation anywhere, then it probably does not exist any more. The thread you are referring to is 3.5 years old by now, so what it says there, isn’t necessarily still the case. Facebook API development moves rather fast.

Comment: Thanks. We check it and you correct.